# @IBDesignable UiView draw(_ rect: CGRect) works in IB but not on device

Tags: swift3, core-graphics, drawrect

I have a circle progress in a draw rect function that is a subclass of UIControl. Swift 3, Xcode 8.

It looks like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        let center = CGPoint(x:rect.size.width/2.0,y:rect.size.height/2.0)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(UIColor.cyan.cgColor)
        ctx.setLineWidth(40)
        ctx.setLineCap(.round)
        ctx.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
        ctx.drawPath(using: .stroke)
}
```

This view is being added programmatically to a @IBDesignable UIViewSubclass

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        self.circleTest = TestCircle(frame: self.bounds)
        self.addSubview(circleTest!)
        setupConstraints() //pins subview to edges of self.
    }
```

Where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: Where is `radius` is getting set?

Comment: I'd suggest a combination of view debugger (make sure the circle view is where you think it should be) and plain ol' debugger/logging (make sure the `rect` and `center` and `radius` are what you think they should be). It could be a constraints mistake. It could be a `radius` issue. It's hard to determine on the basis of the information provided.

Comment: As an aside, it's a bit dangerous to use `rect` parameter to infer size/center of the circle. I'd suggest you refer to `bounds` instead. As the [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw): `rect` is "the portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire visible bounds of your view. However, during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view."

Comment: the radius is set in the init function. radius = self.frame.size.width/2. And that is obviously my problem. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the setting of `radius`. In comments you point out that you're setting it in `init`, and you obviously have to allow for subsequent changes in the frame (esp when using auto layout), so you could move the assignment of `radius` into [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) (or, if you weren't using `draw(_:)`, but rather `CAShapeLayer` or the like, you could do it in [`layoutSubviews()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews)).

Comment: Rob!  It's a case of "Rob better know this ..."  stackoverflow.com/questions/57364895   :)